# Launch a transform with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem : I want to do some kind of spinning wheel (game "roulette") for practice. However I have a problem :

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  
    document.getElementById('img1').classList.remove('rotated');
  
    var deg = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 1); // randomiser
    var div = document.getElementById('img1');
  
    // I want this to rotate to my random position without transition
    div.style.webkitTransition = ""
    div.style.mozTransition = ""
    div.style.oTransition = ""
    div.style.transition = ""

    div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
    div.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
    div.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
    div.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
    div.style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
  
  
  
    // Now I want to spin my wheel 2000deg, with transtion, starting 2 sec later
    setTimeout(function() {
      div.style.webkitTransition = "all 6s ease-in-out"
      div.style.mozTransition = "all 6s ease-in-out"
      div.style.oTransition = "all 6s ease-in-out"
      div.style.transition = "all 6s ease-in-out"
      document.getElementById('img1').classList.add('rotated');
    }, 2000);


}
```

```css
#img1 {
  background: url(http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=339×339&w=339&h=339);
  width: 339px;
  height: 339px;

}
#img1.rotated {
    -webkit-transform : rotate(2000deg); /* I want to spin my wheel of 2000 deg */
    -moz-transform : rotate(2000deg);
    -ms-transform : rotate(2000deg);
    -o-transform : rotate(2000deg);
    transform : rotate(2000deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="img1" style="-webkit-transition: all 6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 6s ease-in-out;
transition: all 6s ease-in-out;"></div> <!-- The image to spin, the transition are here so I can delete them and replace them -->

<button id="button">rotate</button> <!-- My button -->

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the randomizer works, but then my wheel doesn't spin two seconds after :(

The steps I want it to do :

- Go to a random position immediatly
- wait 2 seconds
- then spin with animation
- repeat at the next click on the button

thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `setTimeout`, set your transforms with 2000 degrees:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  div.style.webkitTransition = "all 6s ease-in-out"
  div.style.mozTransition = "all 6s ease-in-out"
  div.style.oTransition = "all 6s ease-in-out"
  div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(2000deg)';
  div.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate(2000deg)';
  div.style.msTransform     = 'rotate(2000deg)';
  div.style.oTransform      = 'rotate(2000deg)';
  div.style.transition = "all 6s ease-in-out"
}, 2000);
```